# $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$ implies $\lambda^{-1}$ is eigenvalue of $T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

Let $T$ be an invertible linear operator. Prove that a scalar $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{-1}$.

I took a look at the solution. It reads:

"$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $T(v)=\lambda v$ for some nonzero vector $v$. As $T$ is invertible, from the above, we see $\lambda\not=0$. So this means

$$\lambda v \color{red}= \lambda^{-1}T^{-1}(T(v))=T^{-1}v$$

which means that $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{-1}$."

Could anyone explain why the equality in red is valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo, it should be $\lambda^{-1} v = \lambda^{-1} T^{-1} (T (v))$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. You saved me!